# Abide Foundation on Valid Form

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, abide

I have a really strange issue in that I'm using the abide foundation validation plugin and all seems to be ok, I can get a pop a message to appear but the form doesn't actually submit... it just seems to refresh the page.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong:

```
$(document)
// to prevent form from submitting upon successful validation
.on("submit", function(ev,frm) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.blockUI({ 
        message: $('#message'), 
        css: { top: '20%', width: '80%', height: '50%', left: '10%', border: 'none', background: 'none' } 
    }); 
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.unblockUI();
        return true;
    }, 17000); // in milliseconds
});
```

Any help would be great on this, it's stressing me out.

**UPDATE**

I've got a little further

```
$(".form")
  .on('invalid', function () {
    var invalid_fields = $(this).find('[data-invalid]');
    console.log(invalid_fields);
  })
  .on('valid', function () {
      $.blockUI({ 
          message: $('#message'), 
          css: { top: '20%', width: '80%', height: '50%', left: '10%', border: 'none', background: 'none' } 
      }); 
      setTimeout(function () {
          $.unblockUI();
      }, 17000); // in milliseconds
    return false;
    $(".form").submit();
  })
  .on('submit', function(){
    return true;
  });
```

For some reason, though the pop shows for a second and then the form submits... it doesn't seem to wait for my timeout.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I've now managed to get this working, anyone else who's having the same issue you need to submit the raw dom form using the options within BlockUi.

```
$(".form")
      .on('invalid', function () {
        var invalid_fields = $(this).find('[data-invalid]');
        console.log(invalid_fields);
      })
      .on('valid', function () {
          var theForm = this;
          $.blockUI({ 
              message: $('#message'), 
              css: { top: '20%', width: '80%', height: '50%', left: '10%', border: 'none', background: 'none' },
              timeout: 17000,
              onUnblock: function() { theForm.submit(); } 
          });
        return false;        
      })
      .on('submit', function(){
        return false;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".form")
      .on('invalid', function () {
        var invalid_fields = $(this).find('[data-invalid]');
        console.log(invalid_fields);
      })
      .on('valid', function () {
          var theForm = this;
          $.blockUI({ 
              message: $('#message'), 
              css: { top: '20%', width: '80%', height: '50%', left: '10%', border: 'none', background: 'none' },
              timeout: 17000,
              onUnblock: function() { theForm.submit(); } 
          });
        return false;        
      })
      .on('submit', function(){
        return false;
      });
```